# How to marquue sql field on php

Tags: php, sql, field

**Check that code any mistake here??**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mytable`");

    echo '<ul>';

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {

        $result= $row['name'];    

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Name: '.$result.'</marquee>';
        echo '</li>';
}    
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**I want to display mysql field data in marquue**
please help me guys.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? How's the current output different from the expected output?

Comment: You're mixing both `mysql` and `mysqli`. Use only one. MySQLi, preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) both are not same.

Change all `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`.

Comment: `mysqli_select_db` function should only be used to **change** the default database for the connection. You can select the default database with 4th parameter in `mysqli_connect()` (which is what the OP is currently doing -- so that's irrelevant)

Comment: ...   
    
Updated my answer.. :)

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…